# Firefox fails to set focus to text area

Tags: javascript, firefox, textarea, paste, execcommand

I have a script where I am capturing user paste data, manipulating it, and then inserting it back into the same place the user's cursor was. This is because the paste data is HTML and the location the user is pasting in is required to be `textarea` which only accepts plain text. This is the code:

```
<textarea autofocus="true" id="editable" name="editable"></textarea>
```

When the user tries to paste some data, my code redirects the paste to a hidden `contenteditable div`. This loses the caret position, so before switching focus, I save it with:

```
    var storedCaret = textarea.selectionStart;
```

Later, after I have performed the necessary transformations, I attempt to retrieve it:

```
    editable.focus();
    editable.setSelectionRange(storedCaret, storedCaret);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, formattedText);
    }, 50);
```

This works just fine for Chrome (49.0.2623.87 m). But to my immense frustration, in Firefox (43.0.1) the paste doesn't work. From my debugging, at the time execCommand fires, `textarea#editable` is correctly selected as the `document.activeElement` but the paste fails completely.

jQuery is an acceptable solution, but I don't want to have to use any other plguins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the lost and confused souls in my position, this is what I ended up going with:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
        {
            var strLeft = textarea.value.substring(0, currentPos);
            var strRight = textarea.value.substring(currentPos, textarea.value.length);
            textarea.value = strLeft + formattedText + strRight;
        }
```

It's wrapped in an if because insertHTML worked better in Chrome. It basically saves cursor position and then splices in the string. Brute but effective for my needs.